# How to maintain multiple versions of a library

Tags: python

Are there any practical solutions for maintaining multiple versions of a library in a Python environment?

For example, I have one Web framework which is using pluggable design. Under this framework, there can be several applications registered (application and the framework are running in the same python process).

Each application will have itself business logic code and common code, say `common_httplib`. The problem is how can I ensure that the multiple versions of `common_httplib` don't conflict each other?

Each application is expected to use its own copy of `common_httplib` but with different versions. **Absolute import, import hook, imp** etc. don't work because `common_httplib` may import other third party libraries which may have the same version problems.

Following is the code structure of the applications.

Under `$FRAMEWORK_HOME/apps/`, there is:

```
/app1
    /common_httplib (version 1)
    /third_party libs
    /app1 BLO code
/app2
    /common_httplib (version 2)
    /third_party libs
    /app2 BLO code
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do so in the same application.

Note for example that Plone, a large project for which deploys depend on hundreds of packages has the adjusting of "known good versions" of all the packages involved as the main thing that defines a version.

The "right thing to do" is to file a bug report for all the products "A" depending on the older versions of another product "B" which is in conflict, so that they will work with the newer versions of "B", and prepare the patches for fixing those. (and while the bug reports are not accepted, you run your deploy with your fixes)

You could also consider splitting your app in several processes using Interprocess communication, such as xmlrpc - but that depends on what you are doing, and what is the nature of your conflicting packages.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.6, the Python 2.7 library `unittest` was backported to 2.6 as `unittest2`, so Python 2.6 has both libraries.

A test module can choose to use either `unittest` with:

```
import unittest
```

or `unittest2` which has advanced features, with:

```
import unittest2 as unittest
```

In a similar way, you can version your dependencies, but you'll have to change the names of the packages and specify the dependency in your imports.

Comment: Thank you ! But I don't know how to handle this case ? Note the **httpmodule** name is the same between these 2 versions. only one of them can be in sys.modules.

myhttplib1.0 -> httpmodule  (1.0)
myhttplib2.0 -> httpmodule  (2.0)

Comment: That means you'll need to **rename** one of the modules, as well as the shared but incompatible modules it imports. I recommend perhaps `httpmoduleold` for the old one, and try to update your older projects to use the new one, and in the future, unittest your API and try not make breaking changes.